# Hibernate @OneToOne with singly @Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I am currently moving some legacy code to hibernate. In this process I came accross following class:

```
public class Foo {

    private Bar b1;
    private Bar b2;
    private Bar b3;
    private Bar b4;
    private Bar b5;

    public Foo() {

    }

    public Foo(Bar b1, Bar b2, Bar b3, Bar b4, Bar b5) {
        this.b1 = b1;
        this.b2 = b2;
        this.b3 = b3;
        this.b4 = b4;
        this.b5 = b5;       
    }
}
```

Now the interesting part is, that `Foo` can't be mapped to any database table or view, while `Bar` will be mapped to a view. Now obviously I can't use any annotation here like `@OneToOne` or `@JoinColumn` as they rely on an existing table/view.

So I thought about using the HQL query

```
select new com.fooCompany.test.Foo
(from Bar b1, from Bar b2, from Bar b3, from Bar b4, from Bar b5)
```

This also is a bit cumbersome and not "nice to use".

So my question is, is there a way to solve it with annotations, or is this currently the only way to deal with a class like this?

---

<sub>If you have any questions, feel free to ask</sub>